# How to find the scss file we want to modify (Magento1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, scss

I have started to use css files generated from scss files recently.
(I use the default [scss structure of magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html#customizing-theme-sass-struct) 1.9)

Previously, when I needed modify web design of sites, I had found target modification(ex. style.css:9011 #content{background:#fff;}) with chrome console. I had tried to change style in browser, and modified that file.

But in SCSS, I can't find target 'scss' file in browser directly.
And so I need to understand the order of importing scss, and I find the target from searching source. ( this way is inefficiency )

Do you have a good idea how to find the modification scss file??

Comment: I don't know if you mean you have done it but , If you right click inspect in google chrome it gives you the specific elements css . Click on the styles.css:1333 (this is only an example) and it will give you the elements scss file and a position that you have to change.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official [RWD Design Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html), you will want to make your SASS changes in a child theme of RWD. In your child theme's `config.rb` file, you should have `sourcemap=true`. The sourcemap will tell Chrome where to find the underlying SCSS file that the style came from, and you will see that in the Developer Tools.

Here is my full `config.rb` file as an example:

```
if Gem.loaded_specs.has_key?('compass-notify')
    require 'compass-notify'
end

# add_import_path "../../../rwd/enterprise/scss"
add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"

http_path = "/skin/frontend/theme/default/"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
relative_assets = true

environment = :development

if environment == :development
  line_comments = true
  sass_options = { :debug_info => true }
  output_style = :expanded
  sourcemap = true
else
  output_style = :compressed
end
```